# C# JSON Rest Response String

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, response

C# noob here.

I'm doing a simple wcf service RestAPI, so far so good...but my json string response isn't coming out the way i wanted.

Actual response:
**{"GetInfoResult":{"Name": "John"}}**

Desired response:
**{"Name": "John"}**

how do I remove *GetInfoResult* field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set the BodyStyle to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` on your `WebGet` annotation, the default is `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` that adds the wrapper you don't want;

```
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
```